# Is there a common web authentication control for WPF similar to WinRT's WebAuthenticationBroker?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, webbrowser-control, winrt-xaml

WinRT/XAML has the neat `WebAuthenticationBroker` helper that makes web authentication (with OAuth or similar methods) easy(ier). Now I'm trying to get OneDrive authentication going and the [docs suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631817.aspx) I should use the WinForms' (doh!) `WebBrowser` control to authenticate. This doesn't sound complicated, but it seems like there might be an easier method. Has someone created a `WebAuthenticationBroker` for WPF or a similar helper that I could use or do I have to stop working on my app and create it myself? Surely people must have done web authentication in desktop apps many times and possibly wanted to share the code with a WinRT app, right?

Comment: The docs you linked are the Desktop app docs. Windows Store apps have their own guide (along with mobile apps) that use the Live SDK. Check out the guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx). Live SDK is available through Nuget.

Comment: I don't care about Windows Store app. I am indeed asking about `WebAuthenticationBroker` implementation for desktop, ideally WPF, though WinForms is just about the same thing. I actually started working on it and have a prototype, but it seems like the WPF `WebBrowser` control doesn't return http status codes which somewhat limits what you can do in terms of error handling/reporting. There's a more fully featured browser control implementation on CodeProject but I don't want to go there yet.

Comment: Ah! Misread that last sentence. It may be better to do the requests with `HttpClient` and use `NavigateToString`. You can use Navigating to intercept and cancel the `WebBrowser` web request, then retrieve the response yourself. Unfortunately, I don't have a sample of this.

Comment: I'm not navigating to a string though. I'm navigating to the authentication UI page so I do need to display it with some version of the `WebBrowser` control (really a shdocvw thingy).

Comment: That is true, but you can download the page manually with `HttpClient` (the server should return the raw html). You can then use that to navigate to the html as a string. Then, using the Navigating event, you can intercept the submit request from the `WebBrowser` and call it manually using the same `HttpRequest`. You can then check the response which should have all the status codes and content that you need for error handling/reporting. On success it may return a new page with capabilities requested, etc. You can navigate to the returned page string if this is the case.

Comment: I could try that, but it feels like any additional files linked from the main html file might not resolve if I try to load the main one from a string. Anyways - I didn't want to get too much into discussing development details here. I'm just looking for an existing API, library or... toolkit.